# Как получить полный путь к файлу onActivityResult() android?

Tags: java, android, файлы, android-intent

Делаю подобие файлового менеджера и столкнулся с проблемой. Я получаю файл из проводника путем выбора его через интент:

```
if (isReadStoragePermissionGranted()) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.setType("*/*");
    startActivityForResult(intent, 7);
} else {
    isReadStoragePermissionGranted();
}
```

и вот как обрабатываю:

```
 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (requestCode == 7 || resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (data != null) {
                Log.i("m", String.valueOf(Objects.requireNonNull(data.getData()).getEncodedPath()));
              }

        }
    }
```

я получаю например такой путь:

```
/document/primary%3ADownload%2F6.apk
```

но это не то что я пытаюсь получить. Например можно получать таким образом через File:

```
File file =... ;
file.getPath();
```

и выводится правильный путь. Есть ли что-то такое и в моем случае, так как я потом буду файл по пути переводить в Base64 и нужно чтобы путь был правильным. Нашел такой способ:

```
public String getRealPathFromURI(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
        Cursor cursor = null;
        try {
            String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri,  proj, null, null, null);
            assert cursor != null;
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null) {
                cursor.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

но как-то не очень правильно получаю путь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем получилось сделать так:

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == code) {
            if (data != null && data.getData() != null) {
                Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();

                String selectedImagePath = ImageFilePath.getPath(
                        this, selectedImageUri);
                convertFileToString(selectedImagePath);
                Log.i("m", selectedImagePath);
            }
        }
    }
```

получаю нормальный путь который можно потом использовать. Может кому поможет.

Answer (score 1):

Не всё так просто. Там очень много разных кейсов, в зависмости от того, откуда пользователь файл выбрал.

Посмотрите [FileUtils](https://github.com/coltoscosmin/FileUtils), а именно: [`getPath`](https://github.com/coltoscosmin/FileUtils/blob/master/FileUtils.java#L283) метод.

Comment: мне этот класс полностью использовать нужно, или только часть? потому что там многовато зависимостей и если вы говорите что все зависит от того откуда пользователь взял файл, то вероятнее всего нужно будет брать весь класс для решения моей проблемы?

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko лучше весь, да. Но, опять же, даже там не все кейсы предусмотрены. К примеру, если пользователь выбрал файл с Яндекс.Диска, то этот метод не отработает нормально =/

Comment: я так вижу что затея не очень делать такой свой менеджер, но все-равно спасибо за помощь :)

Comment: Да уж скажем честно - нет стопроцентно-гарантированного способа получить реальный путь реального файла от провайдера. Провайдер не обязан его предоставлять и контент может быть вовсе и не файлом.

Comment: @woesss, у меня как-бы есть уже рабочий способ получения файла на основе страшненького диалога с recyclerView, но решил попробовать этот способ, может будет работать, но метод класса getPath не дал никакого результата к сожалению :(

Answer (score 1):

Недавно ломал голову над этой проблемой. Для себя я нашел такой способ. Попробуйте. Может и вам подойдет.

```
 @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == CODE_OPEN_FILE) {
            if (data != null && data.getData() != null) {
                String uriString = data.getDataString(); 

            }
        }
    }
```

Получается в переменную `uriString` сохраняем информацию полученную из `Uri` файла.
Затем можно получить `Uri` из этого `uriString` и например использовать в `InputStream`:

```
InputStream inputStream = contentResolver.openInputStream(Uri.parse(uriString));
```

Comment: не получается получить нормальный путь, что-то типа такого - content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary%3ADownload%2Favatar.jpg, а потом его как путь в файле использовать не получается

Comment: вот поэтому я решил использовать для открытия файла не путь, а Uri.

Comment: так я файл не открываю)) мне нужен полный путь, сейчас добавлю свой вариант решения, нашел способ рабочий :)